# How to disable email notification in PrestaShop?

Tags: prestashop

I'm looking for a way to disable some email notifications in PrestaShop.
As I know there is no way to do this without customizations.
And as I see it can be done by overriding `MailCore` class.

Is it really bad idea?
Can I disable email notifications in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It mostly depends on what kind of notifications you are trying to disable:

- **Order status update notifications**: these can be disabled easily via the Admin panel in the Order statuses list. Edit the desired status and simply uncheck the box.
- **Merchant 'New order' notifications**: these can be disabled via the configuration page of the 'mailalert' module.
- **Other notifications**: depending if these are related to modules or not you might be able to turn them off on a case-by-case basis.

In case the notifications you are trying to disable are still not in this list, then an Override of the Mail.php class seems the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Class override is not a very good option.
You should consider some other ways to achieve this.
For example, you can use `actionEmailSendBefore` hook to disable an email notification.
I took this approach from one of [the paid](https://magery-themes.com/prestashop-disable-emails.html) modules.